# Android listview background color on pressed

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview (and a gridview). When the user pressed on an item it gets an orange background. I want to change the color of that case.

I tried to create a selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@color/drawer_list_selector" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/drawer_list_selector" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/drawer_list_selector" android:state_hovered="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/drawer_list_selector" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/drawer_list_selector" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/drawer_list_selector" android:state_activated="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/drawer_list_selector" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/> 
</selector>
```

And have tried putting it as a background to the ListView and its cell's layout. The last time I tried to put a transparent background on the listview and the selector on the cell. Still nothing, the color continues to be the default orange. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setSelector(int)

Comment: Remove the `state_window_focused`. It'll appear selected all the time if you don't - the window is active most of the time.

Comment: from what i understand you want the item to change, not the listview itself. So set the background to the xml your inflate for each row, not the whole listview